# how do I switch between overload functions in c++

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to switch which function overload I call in a class by the value of an int member variable.  Like.

```
class someclass
{
    private:
     int tag;
     SomeArithmeticType val;
     // some class members
   public:
     void setvalue (int I){val = I; tag = 0}
     void setvalue (float f) {val = f; tag = 1}
     void setvalue(other o){val =o; tag=2}
     int method(){}
     float method(){}
     other method(){}
     // rest of class
}

main
{
     // stuff
     some class s;
     s.setvalue(9.7654);
     cout << s << endl;
}
```

If tag is 0 I want to use the Int version of method but if it is another number I want the corresponding overload of method.

Comment: Who taught you to use upper case keywords?

Comment: Pretty sure that won't compile since the overloaded functions only differ by the return type...

Comment: @Kay Professor Trollet Trollsson

Comment: Trying to type on my phone and it keeps capitalizing.  Sorry.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This is a perfectly valid beginner question.

Comment: When do you know the value of `tag`? Sounds like a case for template specialization.

Comment: That is correect .  It won't compile like that.  I'm looking for a way to disambiguate the overloads and chose the correct one at runtime.  I found enable_if but it looks like its  for switching out what code gets compiled.

Comment: @B-Man Then you need to provide more code related to runtime (i.e. your main())

Comment: Value of tag is set through a set function I forgot to illustrate after creating a runtime instance of the class.

Comment: You could make an `enum` to store the type, but I still don't see a problem with using templated-class

Comment: This is what [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is for

Comment: You'll have to emulate `std::visit`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d723f8dd66f31af

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have different return types from the same function. You *can* overload function names by having a different parameter list in each definition. I'd suggest using different function names to get different return types.

Comment: That does not answer the question, however

Comment: It does answer the question. The questioner wants to do something illegal. The answer to such a question is "don't do that then."

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I thought that it would be useful to address an underlying incorrect assumption. You do have a good point however.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d723f8dd66f31af

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to overload here, you want a templated-class:

```
template <typename T = int>  /* defaulting to int  */
class SomeClass
{
      private:
         T tag;
      public:
         T method();
};
```

You can't overload function return-type, it has to be same return-type, but can differ in parameters.